# Specifying liveness so a cycle doesn't happen in TLA+

Tags: tla+

I'm writing a specification of a simple client-server interaction to learn TLA+:

```
-------------------------------- MODULE Bar --------------------------------
VARIABLES
    sessionOK, \* if session is OK or expired
    msg        \* message currently on the wire

vars == <<msg, sessionOK>>

TypeOK ==
    /\ sessionOK \in {TRUE, FALSE}
    /\ msg \in {
         "Query",
         "OK",
         "Unauthorized",
         "null"
       }

Init ==
    /\ msg = "null"
    /\ sessionOK = FALSE

Query ==
    /\ msg \in {"null", "OK"}
    /\ msg' = "Query"
    /\ UNCHANGED <<sessionOK>>

OK ==
    /\ msg = "Query"
    /\ sessionOK = TRUE
    /\ msg' = "OK"
    /\ UNCHANGED <<sessionOK>>

Unauthorized ==
    /\ msg = "Query"
    /\ sessionOK = FALSE
    /\ msg' = "Unauthorized"
    /\ UNCHANGED <<sessionOK>>

Authorize ==
    /\ msg = "Unauthorized"
    /\ msg' = "null"
    /\ sessionOK' = TRUE

Expire ==
    /\ sessionOK = TRUE
    /\ sessionOK' = FALSE
    /\ UNCHANGED <<msg>>

Next ==
    \/ Query
    \/ Unauthorized
    \/ OK
    \/ Authorize
    \/ Expire

Spec == Init /\ [][Next]_vars /\ WF_vars(Next)

=============================================================================
```

As you can hopefully see the client can run some query against a server, and if the session is OK, it will get a result, otherwise it gets a message that it needs to authorize and then retry. The session can expire at any time.

I want to ensure that the client eventually will get a result, so I added this line to properties:

```
(msg = "Query") ~> (msg = "OK")
```

Upon model checking, I'm confronted with a counter-example going like this:
Init -> (Query -> Unauthorized -> Authorize -> Expire),
with the part in parentheses repeating indefinitely. My first thought was to make a strong fairness requirement on `OK` step. However the problem is in this scenario `OK` step is never enabled.

I could add things like `[]<><<OK>>_vars` (which reads "it's always the case that eventually `OK` occurs"), but this feels like cheating, and from what I gather specifying liveness using arbitrary temporal formulas -- and not weak or strong fairness -- is frowned upon.

How can I use weak or strong fairness to guarantee that a query will eventually get a response? Or maybe my model is bad? I'm out of ideas...

Comment: How is `OK` supposed to happen? It doesn't look like it's part of `Next`.

Comment: Ah, my bad, must've made a mistake when preparing the minimal example. Will fix in a minute.

Comment: If `OK` can be never enabled, it sounds like a design problem. Are you trying to say "if it doesn't timeout, then it will eventually be ok?"

Comment: Yes, exactly. In the real world if the client gets "Unauthorized" message, it renews the session and immediately retries, and the time it takes to re-try is orders of magnitude shorter that the lifetime of session, so it's not a problem. But I don't know how to model that.

Comment: I think I figured it out after reading this thread https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tlaplus/7KLn9O-rwPo where Lesie Lamport himself points out we can use conjunction in SF. The property is now satisfied.
`Spec == /\ Init /\ [][Next]_vars /\ WF_vars(Next) /\ SF_vars(OK) /\ SF_vars(Query /\ (sessionOK = TRUE))`
Do you think this is OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question. If anyone thinks they have a better answer, please share.

I found this aptly-named thread [How to test a process eventually succeeds after indefinite number of retries?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tlaplus/7KLn9O-rwPo), where Leslie Lamport himself points out we can just assert fairness on a conjuction of an action and some other formula. In our scenario `Spec` then looks like this:

```
Spec ==
    /\ Init
    /\ [][Next]_vars
    /\ WF_vars(Next)
    /\ SF_vars(OK)
    /\ SF_vars(Query /\ (sessionOK = TRUE))
```

Now, what do each of these formulas in conjuction mean? The first three are quite obvious and were included in my attempt at defining `Spec`.

1. `Init` is true on the first state of the behaviour.
2. `Next` is true for every step of the behaviour (with stuttering allowed).
3. `Next` will continue to occur if it continues to be enabled indefinitely, so a system doesn't come to a stop in the middle of message exchange.

Fourth one was my intuition: it fixes the situation where the query is made, and then the session expires.

4. If `OK` is repeatedly enabled (possible to happen) then it will eventually happen.

And fifth is what was missing: it fixes the situation where `OK` was never enabled in the first place, because the session expired before the `Query` could happen.

5. If it is repeatedly the case that `Query` can happen and the session is valid at the same time, it will eventually happen.